# No virtual transactions marked with inventory transaction <InventTransId> AX 2012

Tags: transactions, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

this is my problem. 
I have a Purchase Order related to a Project. Row is created and the linked Sales Order is created with related item requirement row. The marking ref is created.
But when i want to receive that row, it give me this error: "No virtual transactions marked with inventory transaction ".
This error occurs one every hundred related-to-project orders.

I found this guide but it is only for AX 2009, (http://blogs.solidq.com/ax/post.aspx?id=13) and in AX 2009 it happened because there wasn't a validity control in project field (in AX 2012 there is it).
 I don't know how to unlock that row. help me thanks

Comment: Link is dead, here is a backup: https://web.archive.org/web/20141024171349/http://blogs.solidq.com/AX/Post.aspx?ID=13&title=%e2%80%98No+virtual+transactions+marked+with+inventory+transaction+%5binventTrans%5d%e2%80%99%3a+Bug+found+in+AX+2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
this is because someone delete the item requirement and than recreate another one making a manual marking to the purch order.
There is a table in AX called InterCompanyPurchSalesReference where every record is a link between a purch order and its item requirement.
when you delete an item requirement, you will delete automatically that record and when you try to make a receipt it will search a record in that table but there isn't, so it will search a virtual transaction.
Solution: create a record in that table with purch id and new sales id.